# jquery changed the image id script

Tags: jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/2/

and its working good.
Now I add to each image id the word "size". like this:

```
<img src='images/size1.png' alt='img1' id='size1' />
<img src='images/size2.png' alt='img2' id='size2' />
<img src='images/size3.png' alt='img3' id='size3' />
<img src='images/size4.png' alt='img4' id='size4' />
```

because I change the ID the script isn't working anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/6RTr7/

what do I need to change in the script for it to work?

Comment: Well `$("#dogSizeBox #"+id).addClass('border-highlight');` just selects `#2` so you need to change this selector. And here `$(this).attr("id")` you probably need to remove the `size` from the `id`

Comment: The IDs in your fiddle don't match your code here. Also, please post your jQuery here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/7/
check this

Comment: Also, it is better to use just `$("#"+id)` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = "2";
    $("#dogSizeBox #size"+id).addClass('border-highlight');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6RTr7/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Update the value of your `id` variable in your onReady callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = "size2";
    $("#dogSizeBox #"+id).addClass('border-highlight');
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGHmF/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fGHmF/12/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = "size2";
    $("#dogSizeBox #"+id).addClass('border-highlight');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the following and it will work

```
$("#dogSizeBox #size"+id).addClass('border-highlight');
```

I have added the word "size" right after "#" sign, tested on fiddler and is working.